# Protecting an activity from being mirrored

Tags: android, screen-recording

Is is it possible to detect screen mirroring of my activity in android, I have three thoughts on this:

> 1) I can get all `displays()` and then check if they are greater than 1.
>
> 2) Maybe check if the device is USB connected to a monitor or something else.
>
> 3) Give the activity a flag SECURE (not sure if it helps in all types of mirroring).

What is your opinion on that?